# "Object Expected" error while capturing the page load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The following code inside the  tags gives error: "Object Expected".

```
    <!-- JQuery/AJAX-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("p").load(function(){
                    MakeRequest('divElectionCategory','ulElectionCategory','SELECT * FROM electioncategorymaster', 'UnOrderedList');
                });
            });
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    </script>
```

The MakeRequest function resides in a separate .js file and I have included that file before the above given code.

Which object it is referring to?

**Edited:
The MakeRequest function**

```
function MakeRequest(DivName, ControlName, SqlQuery, ControlType)
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
  var strUrl = "";

  if (ControlType = 'DropDown')
      strUrl = "../phplibraries/filldropdown.php?DivName=" + DivName + "&DropDownControlName=" + ControlName + "&SqlQuery=" + SqlQuery;
  else
      strUrl = "../phplibraries/createelectioncategorymenu.php?DivName=" + DivName + "&ulName=" + ControlName + "&SqlQuery=" + SqlQuery;

  alert(strUrl);
  try 
  {
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
        {
            HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText, DivName);
        }
    }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", strUrl, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

I know there is a big security issue above but please ignore it at this point of time.

Comment: What is `HandleResponse` doing? Why not just use `$.load` as its intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `load()` that way.

The first parameter of `load` takes a URL not a function. Perhaps you meant this:

```
$("p").load( MakeRequest('divElectionCategory','ulElectionCategory','SELECT * FROM electioncategorymaster', 'UnOrderedList') );
```

That assumes that `MakeRequest` returns a formatted URL.

**EDIT**

`.load()` when used against a DOM element and the first parameter is a function, jQuery assumes you are attaching an event handler. However, `p` does not have a load event. If you want to wait for everything to load, try this (It doesn't have to be in DOM ready):

```
$(window).load( function(){
   MakeRequest('divElectionCategory','ulElectionCategory','SELECT * FROM electioncategorymaster', 'UnOrderedList')
});
```

**MakeRequest rewrite**

```
function MakeRequest(DivName, ControlName, SqlQuery, ControlType)
{
  var strUrl = "", params = {};

  if (ControlType = 'DropDown'){
    strUrl = "../phplibraries/filldropdown.php"; 
    params = {
      DivName: DivName,
      DropDownControlName: ControlName,
      SqlQuery: SqlQuery
    }
  } else {
    strUrl = "../phplibraries/createelectioncategorymenu.php";  
    params = {
      DivName: DivName,
      ulName: ControlName,
      SqlQuery: SqlQuery
    }
  }


  alert(strUrl);
  $.get(strUrl, params, function(data){
    HandleResponse(data, DivName);
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh Doug, its you. Yes it worked but the .js file that contains the MakeRequest function also contains an alert() in the MakeRequest. It is not displayed. I guess it is not reaching MakeRequest.

Comment: Can you post what the MakeRequest looks like? Just to be sure are you thinking `load` is an event on the `p` element? Or are you trying to make an AJAX request?

Comment: RPK, why not use jQuery's AJAX methods?

Comment: @Doug: I did like that before.

Comment: I rewrote the MakeRequest function using jQuery AJAX methods.

Comment: Trying it and come back to you after some time.

Comment: @RPK try removing things one by one until the error goes away. For instance remove just the `HandleResponse` call, but leave the rest of that anonymous function alone. There is a lot of nested functions, so its hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Doug: If I put alert(), just above HandleResponse, it is coming there.

Comment: Hey man, I am done for tonight. Ok, maybe the error is in HandleResponse. Can you post or post via http://pastie.org and share the link?